# Spyder : "An error ocurred while starting the kernel" Error. What's the reason ? How can I solve?

Tags: python, spyder

- Python 3.8 version
- Windows 10

An error ocurred while starting the kernel

The error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\spyder\plugins\ipythonconsole.py", line 1572, in create_kernel_manager_and_kernel_client
kernel_manager.start_kernel(stderr=stderr_handle)
File "D:\anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\jupyter_client\manager.py", line 240, in start_kernel
self.write_connection_file()
File "D:\anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\jupyter_client\connect.py", line 547, in write_connection_file
kernel_name=self.kernel_name
File "D:\anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\jupyter_client\connect.py", line 212, in write_connection_file
with secure_write(fname) as f:
File "D:\anaconda3\lib\contextlib.py", line 112, in __enter__
return next(self.gen)
File "D:\anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\jupyter_client\connect.py", line 102, in secure_write
with os.fdopen(os.open(fname, open_flag, 0o600), mode) as f:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\MEHMET\\AppData\\Roaming\\jupyter\\runtime\\kernel‑a8750a464663.json'
```

Comment: did you try to run as admin?

Comment: Thank you so much. I tried and solved the problem.

Comment: selim-çakır  you should change the accepted answer as @CarlosCordoba have a better solution

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This kind of error

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied:
```

is normally because you need to run the script as admin

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) Sorry to say it, but in this case you're wrong. This is a problem caused by an incorrectly implemented feature in the `jupyter_client` package and fixed by doing `conda update --all` in the Anaconda Prompt. By suggesting the OP to run Spyder as admin, you're potentially making them to break their entire system because Spyder can run arbitrary Python code. So I hope you can amend or (even better) remove your answer.

Comment: @CarlosCordoba please put your comment as an answer and i would gladly delete mine

Answer (score 1):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) This is a problem caused by an incorrectly implemented feature in the `jupyter_client` package and fixed by doing `conda update --all` in the Anaconda Prompt.